# result defined but result.data undefined in .then()

Tags: node.js

I have a little problem in this code :

```
router.get("/validate/:nickname/:token", (req, res) => {
  const nickname = req.params.nickname;
  const token = req.params.token;
  TmpUser.find({nickname: nickname, _id: token})
    .select("nickname email password")
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      if (result.length === 1) {
        console.log(result + " ||| email => " + result.email + " password => " + result.password);
        const user = new User({
          _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
          email: result.email,
          password: result.password,
          level: 0,
          nbcommands: 0
        })
        user
          .save()
          .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json({
              message: "user created",
              user: user
            });
          });
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: "user not found",
        });
      }
    });
});
```

In this code in my console.log the object result is defined but when I want to access to result.email for example, it says that it is undefined.

this is the result of console.log(result) btw :

```
{ _id: 5c1a7ee340f7876b08078ac2,
   nickname: 'morgan',
   email: 'morgan@gmail.com',
  password:
    '$2b$10$YNGN.QbtIqKn6ECA/7EazOGC4D/Bq.1hRGIQLHXmcq529SHs0K.ia' }
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like the result has no `email` property? `result.length === 1` seems to imply that you're expecting it to be an array, not an object

Comment: what does the result object console.log?

Comment: it's strange, because when I display result, there is a mail property filed correctly. That's why I don't understand

Comment: i wrote it into the original post

Comment: Can i display this as code like in my message btw ?

Comment: what do you get back from console.log(Array.isArray(result))? if you get true then result is an array and you need to access your fields by indice (result[0].email)

Comment: well played Jonathan it was obvious. Of course it returns an array so i need to precise that i want to access array[0].email !
thanks man !

Comment: Why are you checking .length if result is a object (`{ ... }` is a object in JavaScript).

Comment: For future reference, a debugger will be your best friend.  Just set a breakpoint just before your code `const user = new User()` and you can see exactly what kind of object `result` is.  The bug would've been fixed in less than a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its because MongoDB will be returning data as an array of objects.**

You have already checked if the result is an empty array or not using `result.length === 1`. Try to read the result using the index number as given below,

```
const user = new User({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      email: result[0].email, // use index[0] to get first element
      password: result[0].password, // same here too
      level: 0,
      nbcommands: 0
```

Comment: Surely the result object shouldn't be undefined, if that was the case?

Comment: If the result object is undefined, it will not get inside the condition where he checks the length is === 1. 

if result which is returned by MongoDB doesn't contain any value it will be an array of empty data, so the length will be 0.  So it will not satisfy the 'If' condition.